# Eigenvalues and eigenspace of a linear transformation from $M_{2\times2}$ to $M_{2\times2}$

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations

Let $T:{M_{2\times2}} \to {M_{2\times2}}$ be defined as

$$T(A) = \left( {\matrix{
   2 & 1  \cr 
   1 & 2  \cr 
 } } \right)A - A\left( {\matrix{
   2 & 1  \cr 
   1 & 2  \cr 
 } } \right)$$

Find all eigenvalues of $T$ and a basis for each eigenspace.

How would you do this?

Comment: Hint, $2A=A2$ so you can replace the $2$s with $0$s. Hint, find the $4\times 4$ matrix of $T$ wrt the usual basis of the matrix space.

Comment: This is the matrix I got for the matrix of transformation \begin{bmatrix}
        0 & -1 & 1 & 0 \\
        -1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
        1 & 0 & 0 & -1 \\
          0 & 1 & -1 & 0 \\
        \end{bmatrix}

Comment: Well now you work out the eigenvalue equation, clearly $X^2(X^2-4)$ and solve the usual linear equations for the eigenvectors.

Answer (score 1):

The map $T$ associates to a matrix $A$ its commutator with the fixed matrix $B=(\begin{smallmatrix}2&1\\1&2\end{smallmatrix})$. A first thing you can do is add to$~B$ a multiple of the identity that commutes with every$~A$, so that commutators will be unchanged; we can therefore define the same linear map as the commutator with $B'=(\begin{smallmatrix}0&1\\1&0\end{smallmatrix})$.

Such commutator maps always have a nontrivial kernel (which forms the eigenspace for$~\lambda=0$), namely those matrices that commute with$~B$ (or$~B'$) which at least contains the polynomials in$~B$. Those polynomials form the subspace spanned by $B'$ and $I_2$, and this turns out to be the whole kernel. We'd like to concentrate next on a $T$-stable complementary subspace to the kernel, and if such a subspace exists, it is the image of$~T$. Indeed that image, which is spanned by $J=(\begin{smallmatrix}1&0\\0&-1\end{smallmatrix})$ and $K=(\begin{smallmatrix}0&-1\\1&0\end{smallmatrix})$ is complementary to the span of $I_2$ and $B'$. So we compute $T(J)=2K$ and $T(K)=2J$, so on the basis $[J,K]$ the matrix of the restriction of $T$ to its image is $(\begin{smallmatrix}0&2\\2&0\end{smallmatrix})$. The eigenvalues of that matrix, which are also the nonzero eigenvalues of$~T$, are $\lambda=-2$, with corresponding eigenvectors the scalar multiples of $J-K=(\begin{smallmatrix}1&1\\-1&-1\end{smallmatrix})$ and $\lambda=2$ with corresponding eigenvectors the scalar multiples of $J+K=(\begin{smallmatrix}1&-1\\1&-1\end{smallmatrix})$.

Comment: Omg I am so sorry. This is a linear transformation from M2x2 to M2x2 , not from M2x2 to P2.  I just fixed my question! Again, apology for the mistake!!

Comment: No problem, my answer was assuming that already (when talking about eigenvalues, the linear map _has to_ map a space to itself).